# Play music in background mode: Universal Windows Platform app

Tags: uwp

I have made an Universal Windows App (using html, js and css), for playing music from web hosted mp3 files. It plays the files with html5 audio control.

All works great but when I minimize the app, the audio stops.

I added this in the package.appxmanifest

```
<Extensions>  
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="BackgroundAudioTask.MyBackgroundAudioTask">  
        <BackgroundTasks>  
            <Task Type="audio" />  
        </BackgroundTasks>  
    </Extension>  
</Extensions>
```

And this too:

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap3:Capability Name="backgroundMediaPlayback" />
</Capabilities>
```

But the same.... Audio stops when minimize

Answer (score 0):

I think the step you've missed here is subscribing to the SystemMediaTransportControls since you've written an HTML app and are using the audio element. Apps that use the UWP MediaPlayer instead get that integration automatically.

The docs and samples explain this key requirement.

See MSDN “Requirements for background audio”:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio

The SystemMediaTransportControls sample will help with the specifics:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SystemMediaTransportControls

The key part is to enable Play/Pause:

```
systemMediaControls.isPlayEnabled = true;
systemMediaControls.isPauseEnabled = true;
```

And to handle the button press events for those:

```
 systemMediaControls.addEventListener("buttonpressed", systemMediaControlsButtonPressed, false);
```